# Ordered collection with unique elements and replacement of oldest ones

Tags: java, android, arrays, collections, set

Is there an ordered collection in Java/Android that allows to add unique elements but replacing the oldest ones with new same items? For instance, if my collection is this:

```
["foo", "bar", "alice", "bob"]
```

and I add again `bar`, the desired result would be:

```
["foo", "alice", "bob", "bar"]
```

Furthermore, it would be great if that collection allows to pop the last element in `O(1)`.

**Edit**

The solution that sounds best to me so far is using `ArrayList` as following:

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

[...]

if(!myArray.contains(myString)) {
    myArray.remove(myString);
}

myArray.add(myString);
```

Comment: Maybe just remove the element before you add it again, then you achieve the same effect with ArrayList or Vector.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382529/limited-sortedset ?

Comment: not sorted only ordered right..?

Comment: @Alatau: yes I know, but using for instance the ArrayList that implies an ``O(n)`` computation in the worst case, so I'd like to avoid this. 

@user158037: it looks that doesn't solve my problem.

@ShekharKhairnar: yes, right... only ordered.

Answer (score 1):

[SortedSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) represents a set that is *sorted according to some criterion* (you could define your own Comparator), so take a look on implementations: [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html).

In addition to the SortedSet interface, there is also the [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) class. 
It remembers the order in which the elements were inserted into the set, and returns its elements in that order.
LinkedHashSet is *ordered*, has *predictable iteration order* and allows to *re-insert existing values* (but without affecting insertion order).

Comment: Yes, maybe a solution could be using LinkedHashSet, but I need to remove existing elements before adding them again.

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap is very close to your requirement but you have to find a structure to implement your order. You can use comparable interface to sort data but ordering based on insertion should require also a combination with Queue.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted
>   according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator
>   provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.
>   This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the
>   containsKey, get, put and remove operations. Algorithms are
>   adaptations of those in Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest's Introduction
>   to Algorithms.
>
> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map,
>   and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be
>   consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement
>   the Map interface. (See Comparable or Comparator for a precise
>   definition of consistent with equals.) This is so because the Map
>   interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a sorted
>   map performs all key comparisons using its compareTo (or compare)
>   method, so two keys that are deemed equal by this method are, from the
>   standpoint of the sorted map, equal. The behavior of a sorted map is
>   well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just
>   fails to obey the general contract of the Map interface.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashSet` is pretty close to what you want.

`Set` implementations cannot contain duplicate values, and this implementation and is ordered by insertion order. The only 'gotcha' in this comes from the docs:

> Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set.

This means that instead of re-inserting, you need to first remove they value, and then insert it again.

Comment: Why using LinkedHashMap instead of LinkedHashSet? What are the main advantages?

Comment: My mistake... should have been LinkedHashSet. Answer edited accordingly

Comment: However I've been thinking that if I need to remove existing values and then re-add the new ones, a set collection is useless because the duplication is manually managed, right? See the edited part of my question.