# Optimize Sorting Iterable Values after grouping in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have `RDD[(String,(Int, Int)]`, I need to get top 10 values(tuples) for each key after sorting. I tried:

```
val sortedRDD = rdd.groupByKey.mapValues( x => x.toList.sortWith((x,y) => <<sorting logic>>).take(10))
```

This throws `OutOfMemoryException` as `Iterable[(Int, Int)]` is large for few keys for some keys. How should i handle this?, Is there a way to do this without using `.groupByKey()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `aggregateByKey` instead of `groupByKey` to perform the sorting and "trimming" (that keeps only top 10) *while grouping* instead of grouping into potentially-huge groups and only then mapping the result.

Here's how this could look:

```
// your sorting logic:
val sortingFunction: ((Int, Int), (Int, Int)) => Boolean = ???

val N = 10

val sortedRDD = rdd.aggregateByKey(List[(Int, Int)]())(
  // first function: seqOp, how to add another item of the group to the result
  {
    case (topSoFar, candidate) if topSoFar.size < N => candidate :: topSoFar
    case (topTen, candidate) => (candidate :: topTen).sortWith(sortingFunction).take(N)
  },
  // second function: combOp, how to add combine two partial results created by seqOp
  { case (list1, list2) => (list1 ++ list2).sortWith(sortingFunction).take(N) }
)
```

Notice that per group, we always create values that are 10 items or less.

**NOTE**: performance can possibly be improved by performing less "sort" operations (we sort the same list again and again whenever we add another item / list). To solve that, you can consider using a "sorted set" with a limited capacity (see [Limited SortedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8382529/5344058)) as the value, so that each addition efficiently adds or discards the new value without sorting.