# Find biggest prices among huge amount of CSV files

Tags: java, csv, io, out-of-memory

I have 100 CSV files with following content

```
name,price
book,12.4
bread,54.23
```

Each file show content in sorted by price order
I need to find 10 most expensive products through all these files.This is my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public final class FindBiggest extends Assert {

    static class Data {
        public Data(String str) {
            final String[] split = str.split(",");
            this.name = split[0];
            this.price = Float.parseFloat(split[1]);
        }

        private final String name;
        private final float price;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        final List<File> files = Files.walk(Paths.get("/tmp/"))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".csv"))
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .collect(toList());
        final List<Data> collect =
                files.stream()
                        .map(FindBiggest::content)
                        .map(Data::new)
                        .sorted((o1, o2) -> Float.compare(o1.price, o2.price))
                        .limit(10)
                        .collect(toList());
        System.out.println(collect);

    }

    private static String content(final File file) {
        try {
            return FileUtils.readFileToString(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

In case when I have a lot of csv files program throw UOM(Out of memory) how to implement program to sort content in all files non loading all data to memory ?

Comment: You don't have to read all data from files if they are sorted by price. Just take 10 first records from each file. It gave you list of 1000 biggest price elements and then you need to sort this list and take first 10 elements

Comment: I would suggest to work using a buffer, evaluating line by line for each file if the value is bigger than the older one processed. This way you don't need to load the whole file in the memory.

Comment: @ngueno
Let's say that in first file prices are 50 and 40 in second file price 30 , and I load 8 lines, then I will load price 50 from first file go to second and load price 30 , but 40 bigger than 30

Comment: @RafałSokalski Sorted not mean that prices in separate files needs to be equals, for example first file can contains prices 50,40,20 and second file can contains 30,10,5 if I will load only one from first file and from second I will have 50 and 30

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak Important thing is to take 10 elements from each file because you need 10 biggest. Then you will have list of 1000 elements. And if you will sort this list you can get 10 biggest

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak You can evaluate the biggest price per file, you just need to stash it in a map with the file as a key and the price as the value. This way you can evaluate each file separately.

Comment: @RafałSokalski I don't like this idea, what if tomorrow I need to show 1000 biggest prices , load 1000 from each file?)

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak you can put a parameter to function which will take number of elements. It is still less then take all records from each file

Comment: It is better to take e.g 100 elements only when file contain 100000

Comment: @RafałSokalski I know but I thing loading 1000 lines from 100 files will cause OutOfMemory , it will not solve my problem

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak that's why you need to use a buffer, to not load the whole content in the memory

Comment: @ngueno Lets say I load 1000 lines from 100 files to buffer ,then I need to sort all lines in buffer, I don't know how to sort data in buffer non loading it to memory ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak I just did not follow the final objective. You want to find the biggest price among ALL files, or you want to find the biggest price FOR EACH file?

Comment: @ngueno among all files

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak, OK so you will need to have a structure containing the 10 biggest prices (list/set/map for example), the first step is to read line by line of each file, compare with the content of this structure and if it is bigger than some content, replace it with the new value. With this you will read all your files, and keep the biggest prices in a different structure, without the need of loading the whole content in the memory since you will be evaluating the values line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some sorted set limited by certain amount of items. Probably some 3rd party collections libraries provide it, otherwise you can make it somehow like this: [Limited SortedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382529/limited-sortedset). Important thing is that the method `add` of such sorted set must return `false` if collection is full and newly added element falls beyond the limit, and `true` otherwise.

Now, make a loop over the csv files. Inside the loop's body, read records from csv file and add them to the set until `add` returns false (it'd mean that collection is full and no new records from the current csv won't be larger then the current ones - time to proceed to next file).

When the loop is done, resulting set will be the answer.